# Update existing Word document with new document template using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I use the below code to apply new word template to existing word document, but I am getting this error:

> Error: Exception Type: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException
>   Exception Message: Exception calling "Paste" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   Exception Detail: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at System.Object.GetType()
>      at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.EffectiveArgumentType(Object arg)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.FindBestMethod(MethodInformation[] methods, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments, String& errorId, String& errorMsg, Boolean& expandParamsOnBest)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.GetBestMethodAndArguments(String methodName, MethodInformation[] methods, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments, Object[]& newArguments)
>      at System.Management.Automation.ComMethod.InvokeMethod(PSMethod method, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Adapter.BaseMethodInvoke(PSMethod method, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments)

Complete CODE:

```
    function applydoctemplate ()
{
  param(
    [string]$srcfile,
    [string]$dpath
  )
  $source = $srcfile 
  $destination = $dpath 
  $TparentPath = $env:USERPROFILE
  $template = Join-Path -Path $TparentPath -ChildPath “Documents\xxxxxxx\Template.dotx”
  Add-Type -AssemblyName office
  [ref]$SaveFormat = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveFormat" -as [type]
  $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
  $word.visible = $false
  $word2 = New-Object -ComObject word.application
  $word2.visible = $false
  $doc = $word.documents.open($source)
  $doc2 = $word2.documents.add($template)
  $range = $doc.Range()
  $copy=""
  $copy = $range.Copy()
  $range2 = $doc2.Range()
  $range2.Paste($copy)
  $doc2.saveas([ref]$destination,[ref]$saveFormat::wdFormatDocument)
  $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
  $word.Quit()
  $word2.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
  $word2.Quit()
}
```

It's not working for few peoples.
Any Suggestion.

Comment: Could you post an example of the contents of your word document? Also, is the `Get-ChildItem`  part of your working code? If it is, where is the ending } ?

Comment: That error says that "you can't paste because what you are trying to paste to/from doesn't exist".

Comment: Please edit your question and add such information there. And please read [mcve].

Comment: I have just pasted the part of code. I have created a new word file with just "hello" as text. With same word file it's working for me.

Comment: I have Edited my question and added the complete Functional code. This is working for some people and not working for some people... DOn't know. Please help.

Comment: Judging from your error, I would verify that both the source file and the template file exist on the systems this is failing on.

Comment: Yes cross checked that Template and Source file are available

Comment: Don't add lengthy information in comments. Edit your question and append there.

Comment: Edited Question with Detailed Exception Message

Comment: Hi,

I have got the issue, "$range2.Paste($copy)" line is not working on lower version of powershell i.e 4 and below.
Any solution for this.
Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

## defining the path for storing user templates

```
$template = ($word.Templates | Where-Object {
    $.Name -match "Normal.dot"
}).Path
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it